# Create a linux Shell with malloc_hook() defined

Tags: c, linux, terminal, malloc

I want to create a linux shell with overridden malloc() i.e. malloc_hook().
My terminal should take an .exe file as input and run the program as a thread. Whenever there's a malloc() call in the program, terminal's malloc_hook()  should be called eventually. How can I achieve this goal. I have gone through a tutorial to write my own Linux terminal link : https://abhijangda.wordpress.com/2013/04/14/creating-a-simple-linux-terminal-in-c/ but that wasn't just enough.

Comment: This is remarkably similar to http://stackoverflow.com/q/35382048/1566221

Comment: Yes, the person who posted it is my group member

Comment: By "terminal" do you really mean "shell"?

Comment: @John Hascall Yes, a shell

Comment: Hmmm, that link *is* actually about writing a terminal.  In a windowed system, the **terminal** is the visible part that shows the characters and takes the keyboard input and so on.  The terminal runs a single program.  Almost always this single program is a **shell** (like *bash* or similar).  The shell, is what interprets your "command lines" and runs other programs.

Comment: Right, I just edited my question.

Answer (score 0):

Using `malloc_hook` does not have much to do with the Linux terminal. You can look at the man page for `malloc_hook` to try and understand how it works. but it seems to have been deprecated in recent versions of the glibc:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_hook.3.html

You can also read the manual page for `mallopt` for other ways to tweak the allocation system:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/mallopt.3.html

If the program is yours, use `malloc_hook` as documented above.

If you cannot recompile the program, you may achieve your goal by making a library that replaces all of the `malloc` family of functions and dynamically link the program with this library before the C library, using `LD_PRELOAD` as documented here:

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html

And as discussed in this question:  [What is the LD_PRELOAD trick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick)